# how to select and update at the same time in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I want to select some rows and immediately update a process column in that row as 'Y' before another thread comes and picks it up.

How to do this in Oracle

Initially I had a select for update query which isnt working. what are the ways to achieve this in multi threading mode.

I am using Oracle and couldnt find answers related to oracle in this forum?

Please help

Comment: did my suggestion solve your problem?

Comment: yet to try your solution. shall update tomorrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way of doing it:

Create a table called **test**:

```
create table test (id number, col_to_update varchar2(20));
```

Insert data into table **test**:

```
insert into test values (1, 'BOB');
insert into test values (2, 'PETER');
insert into test values (3, 'BOB');
insert into test values (4, 'PETER');
insert into test values (5, 'BOB');
```

Run PL/SQL block:

```
declare
  cursor c1 is
   select id
        , col_to_update
          from test
         where col_to_update = 'BOB'
    for update of col_to_update;
begin
   for c1_rec in c1 loop
       update test
              set col_to_update = 'UPDATED'
            where current of c1;
       commit;
   end loop;
end;
/
```

Result:

You should see all rows with **col_to_update** 'BOB' being updated to 'UPDATE';

Comment: Sorry, this is "slow by slow" processing, and with a commit inside the loop (booo), this is how to hamper performance. -1   Using the UPDATE with WHERE as rationalSpring suggested in another answer would scale better in the long run. (hmm, just noticed the date on this? why'd the dashboard show this to me as if it was more recent?  O.o  oh well)

Answer (score 6):

The "RETURNING" clause in oracle does this.

```
INSERT INTO <table> (c1, c2, .., cn) VALUES (v1, v2, .., vn) RETURNING <expression> INTO <variables>

UPDATE <table> SET (c1) = (v1), (c2) = (v2), (cn) = (vn) WHERE <condition> RETURNING <expression> INTO <variables>

DELETE FROM <table> WHERE <condition> RETURNING <expression> INTO <variables>
```

Comment: I want to select first and then update. I dont know which one to update until i select

Comment: Wouldn't adding where clauses in the above queries solve that?